# Alternative way of header() to stop page refresh form submit

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a web application with a form submit function. People fill in their info and submit the form. But I have the problem that people can resubmit the form when filled in with F5(Page refresh). Now i have used header() before to fix this.

I don't really like header(), because some users need to submit the form with different data... And header() does not work properly sometimes for me.

I am programming in PHP with the symfony framework, Maybe the framework has some kind of function for this, I can not really find out.

I hope people know good working alternative ways of header(). To achieve this.

Comment: Set a session variable.

Comment: If you use symfony - why do you use `header()`?

Comment: @u_mulder This is my first project in symfony, I am learning it. Do you know a good alternative way?

Comment: `RedirectResponse`

Comment: I don't understand why you want to prevent resubmiting form ?

Comment: @AdrienRosi I am creating a test program for a sms api. So double values may exist in a database. But when someone tests it. And keeps refreshing, alot of the same rows will be added, And each sms costs money.

Comment: To me, you should add this restriction in backend validation. You can check in database  the last row added, and throw an error in current action has already been handled.

Comment: @AdrienRosi Well people are able to use the same phone number. I just dont want people being able to spam f5 and keep sending sms'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do something like this with use of `redirectToRoute()` method from your Controller:

```php
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        # create form and handle request
        $form = $this->createForm(YourFormType::class, $data);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /* some logic here */

            # generate flash message
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Your flash message.');

            # refresh page or redirect to other page
            return $this->redirectToRoute('your_route_name');
        }

        /* some other logic */
    }
}
```

More examples on [Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting).

Comment: Yes exactly, Thats what is does now. What has to come withing your_route_name, A HTTP link?

Comment: The `your_route_name` is a name of a single route name from Symfony.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting

Comment: It says return value expected to be an array?

Comment: I cannot help you with that without knowing your code. This method returns `Response` object. Not an `array`. So your method should be properly typed. Check linked documentation.

Comment: I tried it and it does work. Thanks alot, I dont know why i got that error in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect User to the same page using "RedirectResponse" after submitting data, then if User click F5 it will not send another POST Request. You can also use Ajax call for submitting data.